# Regexp to match tabular data

Tags: regex

From below table

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|          Student Info                               |
|+----------------+--------------+-------------+      |
|| Name           | Highschooled | County      |      |
|+----------------+--------------+-------------+      |
|| Rob            | Y            | LA          |      |
|+----------------+--------------+-------------+      |
|                                                     |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to parse the values from columns.
I tried regular expression below in Golang but something is amiss

This regular expression matches only first column

```
`\|\|([[:word:][:space:]]+\|)+?`
```

And this one greedy matches first two columns as one

```
`^\|((\|[[:word:][:space:]]+)+?)\| +\|`
```

Here's my workspace: https://regex101.com/r/sXQdq1/1

Comment: Correct, you are repeating a capturing group, so only the last captured value is kept in the group memory slot.

Comment: How do I capture all the values?

Comment: No way to capture them. After matching the whole line, extract them or split.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, loop over the lines, check if it starts with `||`, then split the line with `|` after trimming off the `|` and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You did not list a language, so I will demo in Python.

You can find the table elements that start with `||` and parse between the `|` for the data fields. This can be zipped together for a dict of the data.

Given:

```
tbl='''\
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|          Student Info                               |
|+----------------+--------------+-------------+      |
|| Name           | Highschooled | County      |      |
|+----------------+--------------+-------------+      |
|| Rob            | Y            | LA          |      |
|+----------------+--------------+-------------+      |
|                                                     |
+-----------------------------------------------------+'''
```

You can do:

```
import re 
pat=r'^\|\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|'

>>> dict(zip(*re.findall(pat, tbl, flags=re.M)))
{' Name           ': ' Rob            ', ' Highschooled ': ' Y            ', ' County      ': ' LA          '}
```

If you don't want the surrounding white space:

```
>>> {k.strip():v.strip() for k,v in zip(*re.findall(pat, tbl, flags=re.M))}
{'Name': 'Rob', 'Highschooled': 'Y', 'County': 'LA'}
```

If you want a *more specific* regex, you could do [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/67rroA/1/) which will only match a table with `Student Info` at the top.